# @types/react-dom DOMAttributes

Tags: .net, reactjs, webpack, asp.net-core

I'm getting over 400 errors when trying to add React to my .NET Core application. I'm using webpack too.

The first error seems to be the key I think
'"C:/Repositories/ps-react/PsReact/PsReact.Presentation/node_modules/@types/react/index"' has no exported member 'DOMAttributes'.

Here's the code for my react app.

```
let mountNode = document.getElementById('container');

class Button extends React.Component<any, any> {
    state = { counter: 0 };

    render() {
        let result = (
            <button onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.state.counter}</button>
        );

        return result;
    }

    handleClick = () => {
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
            counter: prevState.counter + 1
        }));
    }
};

ReactDOM.render(<Button />, mountNode);
```

And here is my package.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "startup",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.1", 
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "ng2-toastr": "4.0.1",
    "react": "15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "15.6.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "5.2.0",
    "systemjs": "0.20.11",
    "typescript": "2.3.4",
    "zone.js": "0.8.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/core-js": "0.9.36",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.46",
    "@types/react": "^15.0.31",
    "@types/react-dom": "^15.5.1",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^4.0.5",
    "angular-router-loader": "0.6.0",
    "bootstrap-loader": "2.0.0",
    "bootstrap-sass": "3.3.7",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "0.1.16",
    "css-loader": "0.28.0",
    "file-loader": "0.10.1",
    "font-awesome-loader": "1.0.2",
    "node-sass": "4.5.2",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "resolve-url-loader": "2.0.2",
    "sass-loader": "6.0.3",
    "source-map-loader": "0.2.1",
    "style-loader": "0.16.1",
    "ts-loader": "2.0.3",
    "typescript": "2.2.2",
    "url-loader": "0.5.8",
    "webpack": "2.3.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.4.2"
  }
}
```

I've also excluded node modules on my tsConfig. The errors aren't preventing me from running the application but that's a lot of errors to ignore..

Cheers,

Z

Comment: ever find an answer to this?